# Past or future neutral time difference -- does my sentence make sense?

Tags: tiempo

> "Que es de 1 año, 2 meses, 16 días, 1 minuto, y 15 segundas a partir de ahora."

Does that accurately translate to:

> "That is 1 year, 2 months, 16 days, 1 minute, and 15 seconds from now"?

Does it make sense if the "from now" indicates either past or future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original sentence in English is both ambiguous and unusual. The ambiguity lies in the word 'that'. Do you mean "That (event) is...", or are you talking about an event "... that is..."?
Instead of your construction, I would rather say the event "is ... in the future" or at least "... from today".

Having said this, it is difficult to find a correct translation. yours is pretty much word-by-word. instead, it makes more sense to find out the expressions actually used in Spanish. Two possibilities are:

- Tendra efecto en 1 año, 2 meses, ...
- Tendra lugar en 1 año, 2 meses, ...

BTW, it is 'segundos', not 'segundas'. Also, contrary to the standard usage in English, the last term of a comma-sparated list has no comma; thus, you end with "...1 minuto y 15 segundos".

Comment: Sorry, the context of "that" was simply to imply the previously indicated time. It was a programming example, in which I generated a date/time (e.g. November 14, 2014 4:42pm) and then indicated the distance in time from the present. The generated date/time may have been future or past without distinction.

Yeah, "segundas" was a typo. But I don't know if I can get over the lack of the Oxford comma in Spanish!

Anyways, thanks for the informative answer.